# Is it possible to link 2 different snippets in Stack Overflow?

Tags: feature-request, design, stack-snippets

When I'm creating 2 different snippets in the same question or answer like this:

Snippet for window 1:

```js
function enableButton() {
  document.getElementById('disabled').disabled = false;
  document.getElementById('disabled').innerText = 'not disabled';
}
```

```html
<a>click me</a>
<br>
<button id='disabled' disabled>im disabled</button>
```

Snippet for window 2:

```js
function enableHim() {
  let oldWin = window.opener;
  oldWin.enableButton();
}
```

```html
<button id='b' onclick='enableHim()'>click here to enable other button</button>
```

Is it possible to somehow link them together? Meaning to use each other's functions and variables? Or even decide how they will relate to each other? In the example above I want snippet 2 to relate to snippet 1 as its opener (when I'm using `window.opener` I want to get snippet 1).

Comment: What is the gain compare with only one snippet with all the code? Too much code in one block, You can put code in normal code block for the explanation and still provide a complete snippet. People won't have to copy past from multiple part. Ps: I'm not trying to be picky, just fail to see the real life scenari..

Comment: I would guess not since the entire point is to have them be isolated sandboxes, where the isolation is "from the rest of the page". Not a JS wiz, though, so it may be possible.

Comment: Well, if it's sandboxed, which I think it is too, they can't access each other by design.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

Because when you click *Run Code Snippet*, the snippet runs in an **iframe**. That is another DOM tree and you cannot access the parent iframes because of the cross-origin policy (CORS) .

It will be like, embedding an iframe in your webpage and to only see that it messes up your webpage by injecting malicious scripts.

The only way to get the functions of another iframe is to first select it and then `.contentWindow.yourTargetFunction();` But you cannot access things outside the frame

This snippet should answer the problem

```js
window.parent.document.getElementById('#target');
```

This feature will not be added in the future because if it is added then it will be a security issue.

Comment: I know that it's possible by doing that. I asked if there is a way for linking snippet or if such a feature can be added

Comment: @OmriAttiya You didn't ask if such a feature could be added, your question verbatim was *"Is it possible to somehow link them together? Meaning to use each other's functions and variables? Or even decide how they will relate to each other?"*, to which weegee provided an adequate and correct response.

Comment: It would be technically possible to link different iframes from different windows together, to an extent, if one controls all sites in question (or only wants to change things for one's self, like with a userscript), but it'd be *really* odd and pretty pointless, at least in this case

Comment: The SOP thing is not the biggest problem, if it was only that, we could hack up something by loading both iframes in the same snippet. The biggest problem is the very restrictive sandbox attribute which will make inner documents have an opaque origin... For instance jsfiddle's iframe is loaded in a cross-origin frame (fiddle.jshell.net), but it's not opaque so the frame content can load and access inner docs just well. https://jsfiddle.net/2v37p18a/.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Why would you want to? You are making new snippets for separate code and now you want them to communicate. That's pointless. Why not put all your things in one snippet?

Comment: Indeed. Like I said, it'd be strange and pointless (at least in the context of Stack Snippets)